# gdbserver doesn't trigger breakpoints

Tags: gdb, breakpoint

I'm debugging a vulnerable app on a remote host. I've set up `gbserver` on the host with:

```
gdbserver host:1234 /my/target/app
```

On my local host I've connected with:

```
$ gdb /same/target/app
gdb$ target extended-remote 192.168.0.100:1234
```

I connect successfully and can proceed to set a breakpoint on a target instruction, ie:

```
$gdb disas vuln_function
....
   0x08048e6b <+116>:   ret
End of assembler dump.
gdb$ b *0x08048e6b
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048e6b
```

Looking at the disassembled function code and having tested this on the host itself, I'm 100% sure I'm breaking on the right address and in any case I'm triggering a buffer overflow which should make `gdb` break by itself.

But instead of getting the usual breakpoint on my `gdb` client, nothing happens. `gdbserver` freezes on the BO (so I'm guessing it did break on the `ret`) without throwing the `segfault`. `gdb` doesn't seem to be crashing or behaving abnormally other than not giving me a prompt on the breakpoint.

**Is there a special way to set breakpoints when debugging with `gdbserver`?**